# Why GKSession always tries to use bluetooth when running on a device and doesn't on simulator?

Tags: iphone, wifi, p2p, gamekit, gksession

I'm trying to implement GameKit connection without using GKPeerPickerController. What i need is to establish WiFi connection, not bluetooth.

This is how i do that

```
self.gameSession = [[GKSession alloc] initWithSessionID:@"test" displayName:nil sessionMode:GKSessionModePeer];
self.gameSession.available = YES;
self.gameSession.delegate = self;
self.gameSession.disconnectTimeout = 0;
[self.gameSession setDataReceiveHandler:self withContext:nil];
```

My problem is that devices always try to connect over Bluetooth. At least i think so cause the following always appears in the console

> BTM: attaching to BTServer

Even if i turn bluetooth off it always tries to deal with bluetooth, not wifi. Moreover - if bluetooth is on - devices never see each other if i don't use GKPeerPickerController. 
Also, simulator never tries to look for bluetooth and is always able to establish wifi connection and find any device easily. How do i make GKSession choose WiFi connection?

Answer (score 0):

May be your issue arising with Jailbroken Device,

GKSession and GKSessionDelegate implementations works for both bluetooth and WiFi.

these two class checks wifi and bluetooth, and choose an appropriate transmission medium.

If your iPhone is Jailbroken, then there might be some issues with BlueTooth or wifi while connecting over those transmission medium, and possibly that is prevent to Work with gamekit Properly.

And also try to use

```
picker.connectionTypesMask = GKPeerPickerConnectionTypeOnline
```

check with Condition in Delegate methods

```
if (type == GKPeerPickerConnectionTypeOnline) {
}
```

Update :

Refer this sample code of Apple..
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GKTapper/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010283

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. i use not jailbroken devices. and my goal is to establish connection WITHOUT using GKPeerPickerController. i have already tried GKPeerPickerController, particularly, pieces of code that you've offered, but unfortunately it doesn't work. Did you ever try using GKSession WITHOUT GKPeerPickerController?

Comment: No mate, i have not use it without GKPeerPickerController.. And why you dont like GKPeerPickerController ?

Comment: cause i need to establish WiFi connection

Comment: so i change my question - did you ever succeed in connecting two devices over WiFi with GameKit?

Comment: ya, with the help of GKSession and GKSessionDelegate, i created one game for two player to play over, Game Center, Bluetooth, Wifi..

Comment: did you create your session like i did above?

Comment: with the help of GKSession and GKSessionDelegate, i want to create a two player to play over Wifi only using the game kit . How can i do please help me...if u have already succeded in doing this one..

Comment: you should go to developer.apple.com and download all sample with GameKit, and you will see one of bluetooth sample which will help you. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GKTank/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008918